# JWT : why do I get a new token after clearing localstorage?

Tags: spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt, angular7

I have an Angular 7 app with a spring API. I use spring security, JWT tokens, and https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc to handle login.

I'm able to login, but when I logout and clic on login once again, I immediately get a new token, without having to connect.
I'm new to spring security and JWT tokens, but from what I know, I cannot properly logout from the back, the classic way is to remove token from the front. That's what the library do, and to be sure I tried by emptying manualy the localStorage (where token is stored), but even with localStorage cleared, when I try to login, I get a new token immediately.

Any idea about what happengin and how can I logout?

Authorization server config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigJwt extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("sampleClientId")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit")
        .scopes("read", "write", "foo", "bar")
        .autoApprove(true)/*.accessTokenValiditySeconds(3600)*/
        .redirectUris("http://localhost:4200");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        final TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("123");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }
}
```

**Edit :**

It seems that this was due to the lack of

```
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
```

But now that I've added it, I'm stuck on the login form, seems that there's still something missing. Here my config :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/registrationConfirm").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/confirm/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/user/registration/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token/revokeById/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/tokens/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().permitAll();
    }
```